# Is there something like flushing regex match special variable?

Tags: perl

I have the following sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $b = "Size: 200 GB";
if ($b =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/) {
    my $match1 = $1;
    print "Match1 : $match1\n";
}

my $match2;
my $c = "Size:  GB";
$c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/;
$match2 = $1;
print "Match2 : $match2\n";
```

If I run this code as-is, $match2 gets the value 200 because $1 is assigned 200 from the previous block. If $c = "Size: 400 GB", then $match2 becomes 400 because $1 values gets populated from  here: $c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/;
I can solve this problem by putting an if statement like 
    if ($c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/) {
    $match2 = $1;
    }
But is there a better way to flush $1's value every time ?

Comment: Why you wanted to do without 'if'?  It actually elminiated error-checking mechanism as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to use the `if()` version. Since your `$c` regex doesn't the match anything, there's no capturing done, so the previous captures are left in place. This non-reset is by design, as per http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups  :

> NOTE: Failed matches in Perl do not reset the match variables, which makes it
>       easier to write code that tests for a series of more specific cases and remembers
>       the best match.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "match in list context" to get the captures (if any):

```
my($match2) = $c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/;
```

If the match fails, $match2 will get the undef value (ie. it will be "reset");

Answer (score 1):

Check the match:

```
my $match2;
my $c = "Size:  GB";
if( $c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/ ) {
   $match2 = $1;
   print "Match2 : $match2\n";
}
```

Otherwise, you don't know if the string really match the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `and` to only set the variable if there's a match:

```
my $match2;
$c =~ /Size: (\d+) GB/ and $match2 = $1;
```

If there's no match, `$match2` will be undefined.